# Content messed up when removing two lines

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex

after wanting to change my report from B5 format to A4 format I did some slight modifications in the standard .sty file (from my university). All in all a nice result in A4 format. However, my only problem seems to be that my content suddenly appears as this:

[image: Content]

This is caused by this piece of code in the .sty file:

```
\addtolength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
```

Unfortunately I am not an expert in LaTeX but I was hopeing you would be able to help get my content back on track such that I can enjoy the A4 format.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the two lines use

```
\usepackage{parskip}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply! 
Why does this event occour?

Comment: in tabulars `\baselineskip` is 0pt. The reason why it makes more sense to use a KOMA-Class with the optional argument `parskip=half-` or the package `parskip`